# %3f and %3d in links in perl

Tags: perl, decoding

I'm newish to perl, and writing a small script that pull links from a page using LWP, the results are decoded into this format:

http://www.perlmonks.org/%3fnode_id%3d376075

rather than:

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=376075

I'm not familiar with that syntax... what is it called? is there an easy way to translate it back?

Comment: [Percent/URL encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is [URL Encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) in action.

There are several perl libraries to help decode and vice versa. Here is one that popped up in a quick search: http://www.perlhowto.com/encode_and_decode_url_strings

Comment: use URI::Escape;

$url = uri_unescape($url); -- worked great, thanks.

Comment: That's wrong. You can never use `uri_unescape` on a url. `uri_unescape` can only be used on extracted components.

Comment: It's working though, it's spitting out http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=376075 when I use it?

Comment: Two wrongs sometimes look like a right. Try it on `http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=%25data`, Then visit the original and the new page.

Answer (score 1):

```
http://www.perlmonks.org/%3fnode_id%3d376075
```

and

```
http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=376075
```

are not equivalent URLs. Applying `uri_unescape` to an url is never correct. It should only ever be used on extracted components. The first accesses a file named `?node_id=376075`. The second access the default file (which happens to be `index.pl`) and passes an arg named `node_id` to it.

Perhaps you actually have something like

```
foo.cgi?redirect=http://www.perlmonks.org/%3fnode_id%3d376075
```

In which case you want to URI. It both extract the parts and decodes them. Properly.

```
use URI qw( );
my $url = URI->new('foo.cgi?redirect=http://www.perlmonks.org/%3fnode_id%3d376075');
my %form = $url->query_form();
say $form{redirect};  # http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=376075
```